# Can't erase my suposedly re-writable DVD

Tags: dvd, rewrite

I need to make a Windows 7 recovery disk.  The problem is that I've only got one DVD lying around the house free to use. It's got a Ubuntu 10 Wubi installation in it which my uncle gave to me ages ago. I should be able to erase everything on it, but I receive a message similar to `Cannot rewrite disk`. Also, there is no link on the toolbar in Windows Explorer, plus burning it comes with the same results. On My Computer it's registered as `DVD RW Drive (E:) Install Ubuntu` and it's storage written below, followed with `CDFS`.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Just because the *drive* is a ReWriteable doesn't mean the *disc* is.

Comment: What kind of disk are you using?  DVD+RW or DVD-RW?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the DVD is rewriteable? Some DVD's have the label "DVD-R" and have a small "RW" logo underneath it but it's **NOT** a rewriteable DVD.

If you have an USB stick lying around, you could also use that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check, but I'm just a bit baffled because the DVD seems to be a clean disk you can buy in the local store and my uncle just put Ubuntu on it. Probably so I guess though, thanks for making it clear.

I have a USB, been trying to use tutorials, but my damned CMD won't work... another question, heh.

Comment: The disk you are trying to use is a DVD-R/DVD+R which can only be written to once.  Go out and purchase a DVD+RW/DVD-RW disk.